# Java Database - absolute URL

Tags: java, jdbc

If I try to connect to my embedded database with :

```java
private static String url = "jdbc:sqlite:~/hr4413/pkg/sqlite/Models_R_US.db";
```

it looks like by default, the path I give is the relative path to the working directory. But I would like to give an absolute path. Is that possible ?

Comment: What Have You Tried? (tm)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/java/raw/doc/overview.html?name=0a704f4b7294a3d63e6ea2b612daa3b997c4b5f1) gives a number of JDBC URL types.  One which should match your use case is:

```
private static String url = "jdbc:sqlite://hr4413/pkg/sqlite/Models_R_US.db";
```

This would match the exact folder path `/hr4413/pkg/sqlite/Models_R_US.db`, where `hr4413` is the top level directory from root.

To find the absolute path from your user directory, do the following:

```
cd ~
pwd
```

Then, observe what the absolute path is, to which you would append `/hr4413/pkg/sqlite/Models_R_US.db` to get your complete absolute path.

Comment: This puts me the error message : `path to '//hr4413/pkg/sqlite/Models_R_US.db': '\\' does not exist`

Comment: @user54517 Because that path doesn't exist.  `~/hr4413` in Linux means to start with your user's home directory.  I have no way of knowing what that is.  Check my updated question.

Comment: Ok, I think I can identify the problem. I'm developing with WSL integrated with windows 10. But normally, I thought that the files were synchronized. I have my file in `C:\Users\myUserProfile\hr4413\...`. But actually, with WSL, files are stored in `/mnt/c/Users/myUserProfile...`